# VB.net Excel ExportAsFixedFormat fails Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to write a very simple VB.net app which would open an excel file and save it as excel.

The environment I am working on is as follows:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2016
- Office 2016

I have successfully managed to open the excel sheet and save to another location. However when trying to open the excel and save as pdf, I get the following error message

> The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Looking into the details of the error, I can see the following:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   {"The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"}
>
> > error code: -2147417851

The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

    Dim sheetname As String = "d:\test\test.xlsx"

    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sheetname)


    xlWorkBook.Activate()
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlWorkSheet.Activate()
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
 xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Filename:=
    "d:\test\test.pdf", Quality:=Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard _
    , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=
    False)





    xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    xlApp.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp) : xlApp = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook) : xlWorkBook = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet) : xlWorkSheet = Nothing
```

Help!

**issue seem to arise due to the Excel sheet having formulas, copying and pasting the content into a new sheet (paste special values and number formatting only) and running the code above works**

Comment: I have managed to replicate your issue with Excel 2016. I first tried it with a blank sheet. I got the error. I then popped some data in (as normally you would have data) and the error did not occur. Have you any data in your worksheet?

Comment: Yes, there's data in there. Did you manage to get it working (with data in sheet) with the code above or did you need to change anything?

Comment: No I didn't. Only thing was I installed the PDF Add on for Excel 2007 which I didn't think would be relevant but I did nonetheless (and rebooted machine).

Comment: Is D on your local PC or on another? I used my C drive. I'm guessing D is local.

Comment: I'll try to install the add-in and yes the d drive is a local drive

Comment: The issue I think is due to formulas in the excel sheet. 
I tried the following:
Copied and pasted (values and formatting only) the content of the excel sheet into a new workbook then ran the above code on the new workbook and it works like a charm!

More digging needed...

Comment: Well that's good then. For the PDF you don't need the formulas, you only need the values. That's the fix right there. Well done on finding the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't solve the problem :) The excel workbook does need to have the formulas, they calculate various values in the sheet which need to be done prior to exporting to pdf

Comment: That's fine. Can you not do all that, then export to another workbook then export to PDF? You can retain the original workbook so you don't lose the values but just do a copy for export purposes.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, not sure if this is by design or if it's a bug, I am pretty certain there should be an easier way of doing this :) Thank you Jinx88909

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right! Thank you to all that tried to help. By reading your responses I kept trying till I figured out the issue.

It appears that ExportAsFixedFormat doesn't like Excel sheets with formulas in. To work around this issue, I just created a new blank worksheet and copied and pasted (values only) the content from my main sheet into it. This seems to work perfectly. I then automated this in my code as follows:

```
    Dim xlworksheet_static As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(2)
    xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "H35").Copy()
    xlworksheet_static.Activate()
    xlworksheet_static.Range("A1", "H35").Select()
    xlworksheet_static.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

    xlworksheet_static.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type:=Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, Filename:=
     "d:\test\test.pdf", Quality:=Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard _
    , IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, OpenAfterPublish:=
    False)
```

Probably not the most straight forward way but I couldn't get it to work otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Save it as .PDF like that:

```
xlWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "d:\test\test.pdf")
```

Comment: That's what I am trying above - it gives the error in the question :)

Comment: on my computer it works fine so the exception probabley evolve from the environment